# How to set android:popupBackground border size/padding?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I wanted to set the background color of a Spinner in Android Studio and have been able to do so with the following code:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/StreamSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#D2B450"
    android:popupBackground="#D2B450">
</Spinner>
```

The issue is that when I added `android:popupBackground="#D2B450"` it put some borders/padding around the selection box which were not there before I added that line. Before I added that line, the selection box with the content was with a white background and no padding/borders.

I have not been able to find out how to remove this while retaining the background color I need (#D2B450).

This is what it looks like with the line in place to set the `popupBackground` (see black borders)

[image]

and this is what it looks like without that line:

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction to remove the borders?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set it programmatically:

```
<color name="spinner_background">#D2B450</color>
```

```
spinner2.setPopupBackgroundResource(R.color.spinner_background);
```

**Option 2:**

If still not working, there is a workaround to create a custom item layout; set it in `android:background`; and fix the ripple effect in `android:foreground`.

spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

And set that to the spinner adapter:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
```

- The drawback that the ripple effect will work only on API-23+

Comment: Thank you, Option 2 worked, much appreciated.